# Datadog instrumentation on Spring boot container application - class not found

Tags: java, kubernetes, instrumentation, datadog

I'm currently running a spring boot application as container into a kubernetes cluster.
Datadog agent is running as containers on the cluster.

I have modified the container image build to include the datadog agent before running the application:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","java -javaagent:dd-java-agent.jar -Ddd.trace.config=datadog.properties -Dlogging.config=/logback.xml -jar service.jar"]
```

I also setup the environment variable to indicate the HOST IP of the agent to my container via the Deployment file.

The problem now is i'm getting this class not found exception when the application starts:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: datadog/trace/instrumentation/springscheduling/SpringSchedulingInstrumentation
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1235)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1277)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClass(AnnotationsScanner.java:128)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.process(AnnotationsScanner.java:107)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:97)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:78)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.scan(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:242)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.get(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:149)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.get(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:131)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:581)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.DefaultSpanNamer.annotation(DefaultSpanNamer.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.DefaultSpanNamer.name(DefaultSpanNamer.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.<init>(TraceRunnable.java:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.<init>(TraceRunnable.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.LazyTraceThreadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(LazyTraceThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.ExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExecutorBeanPostProcessor.java:328)
```

Quite straigtforward, i need to include some dependencies into the application package. But i could not find anything useful on datadog website nor maven central repository.
Including the agent itself or the api libraries fix nothing. This class is present on the agent but under a different path.

Does anybody know which dependencies should be included in the classpath of the application to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring is scanning your classpath that seems incomplete. Maybe it is related to Spring's class loading mechanisms. The [class in question](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/blob/7df5cfe3e3f1710d8840522232f18496dc6be530/dd-java-agent/instrumentation/spring-scheduling-3.1/src/main/java/datadog/trace/instrumentation/springscheduling/SpringSchedulingInstrumentation.java) exists and seems to be part of the agent.

Possibly, you are using an outdated version of the agent.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I made tests with multiple version of the agent and it fails no matter which version is used after 0.43.0 (they introduced this instrumentation in 0.44.0 and actually latest version is 0.46.0). So right now i downgraded to 0.43.0 and will try to figure out where the problem comes from with light demo app

Comment: In this case, it's a bug in the agent. They probably inject a class into Spring that they expect to be loadable but it ends up on another class loader, causing this exception.

Comment: yes i think so. When unzipping their agent i can find this class but in a total different package path. I will just provide them a simple app which fails to start due to that classpath error and post here when it's fixed or they found which of the dependencies provoke this problem. Thanks for your help Rafael.

Comment: Tine have passed and unfortunately i could not reproduce this problem with my updated application code.

Expect usual feature code updates, i also refactored how the Kubernetes auto config discovery classes are configured, and since it was this feature which use the scheduler, it might be related. 

I don't have much time now to investigate and ensure about that but my guess is that under certain configuration spring cloud kubernetes features may instrument the code and this might create conflicts with datadog instrumentation of your code. But again, this is just something to consider.